# How to get ActiveRecord to use row value in where statement

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, scope

I was hoping this would be straight forward but I've been banging my head against it for ages:

```
Manufacturer.where("(select count(*) from manufacturers where name = ?) = 1 OR type = 2", [name value in current row])
```

That should create a query someting like:

```
Select "m".* from manufacturers "m" where("(select count(*) from manufacturers where name = 
"m".name) = 1 OR type = 2"))
```

I want to define a scope to match. Basically I'm trying to find all unique rows where `name` occurs once, or if it occurs more than once, then the row with the associated type.  So if I have:

```
[name 'test' type 1],
[name 'test' type 2],
[name 'test2' type 1]
```

then I get the rows returned:

```
[name 'test' type 2],
[name 'test2' type 1]
```

I tried using `table_alias` and rewording the `where` but as that is global it screws up all sorts of other stuff.  I would love to be able to add a "one-time" alias but I've run out of ideas on that one too.

Comment: What RDBMS (if any) are you using?

Comment: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL so your query is confusing. Might be better to start with the table structure, associations, and what you want the query to do.

Comment: Sorry - OR instead of ||

Comment: I'm using PostGres through Ruby.  It's the Ruby/arel that is creating the SQL from the ruby model scope

Comment: Something like `SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) FROM manufacturers ORDER name ASC, type DESC;` should do it. Its very unclear what you actually want here though.

Comment: How is it very unclear?  I give the records I have, and the records I want from them.  And DISTINCT isn't going to work for me.  The whole point is that the name is duplicated but I want the records with a specified type if they exist, otherwise I want the duplicate